# I Can't Change the Read-Only Status of .class Files in intellij

Tags: java, .class-file

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO9Rp.png)

I downloaded a .class file and opened it in Intellij, I pressed the lock button in bottom right corner and File>Make File Writable but I still can't edit the .class file. I own the file and have full permission.

Comment: This doesn't seem surprising?  `.class` files aren't meant to be edited by hand, they're meant to be the compilation of code that you edit by hand.

Comment: Okay, can I reverse-compile a .class file and edit the code then? And how do I do it?

Comment: This very much sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your actual problem?

Comment: I downloaded a .class file and I want to edit this value:
https://imgur.com/a/2YnNc0A